# Please help for Switch menu to initialize

Tags: android, menu, bluetooth, switch-statement

I'm the beginner for developing Android app. I want to use the Bluetooth connection bar on menu(action bar?). However i can't get the Bluetooth state to switch using sw_Bt.setChecked()
Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater mInflater = getMenuInflater();
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.sw_BT).setChecked(false);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.sw_BT).setChecked(true)
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
//        return true;
    }
```

switch_bluetooth.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/menu_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bluetooth_connect"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/sw_BT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textOn="@string/connect"
        android:textOff="@string/disconnect"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/sw_BT"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_bluetooth"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please describe the error you encounter. "I can't get the Bluetooth state" is not very precise.

Comment: well...i want to get my Blooth Activation State on my action bar(switch) however it doesn't work setChecked() method. it doesn't have run time or other error but In app switch doesn't change when i turn on bluetooth in my phone

Answer (score 0):

You should use onPrepareOptionsMenu for this instead of onCreateOptionsMenu. onCreateOptionsMenu is called ones for initializing the menu. onPrepareOptionsMenu is called every time before displaying menu.

@Override

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.sw_BT).setChecked(false);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.sw_BT).setChecked(true)
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also when ever your state changes call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to call onPrepareOptionsMenu again.

Comment: Thks for response, i added onPrepareOptionsMenu() but it didn't work... there are no errors but switch did not change by bloothtooth state(activation)